# Error in angular core while running npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-cli

Here's the package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.3"
  }
}
```

I tried using node v12 and v14 but I got the same error while running npm start

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 3761:14-27
"export 'ɵRuntimeError' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.js 4210:12-27
"export 'ɵisSubscribable' was not found in '@angular/core'
```